# How to use windows sdk 8.1 with visual studio 2012 update 3

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-8.1

Currently I have windows 8 with visual studio 2012 update 3 installed . I want to use some APIs of windows 8.1 preview which are not supported on windows 8. 
Can I use them by insatlling windows sdk 8.1 ?
If yes , how to switch to sdk 8.1 with visual studio 2012 update 3. ?

Comment: No you cannot use 8.1 APIs for a Windows 8 app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the **msdn social discussion** Somebody asked the same question: [Use Windows 8.1 SDK with VS 2012 Update 3](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/c2c7e2bc-b5c2-4e5b-86b5-bb613468bea7/use-windows-81-sdk-with-vs-2012-update-3)

> Hello Shubhan
>   You will need VS2013 preview on Windows 8.1 Preview to develop apps for 8.1.
>   Since you have Windows 8 Pro, if you don't want to install the Preview at this time, one option would be to enable the Hyper-V feature on Windows 8 and install Windows 8.1 Preview to a virtual machine, along with VS2013 preview.
>   HTH
>   Doug

Comment: Thanks Martin. I went through that link. i was wondering if there was some other solution.

Comment: I do not know other solutions but if you found another one. I will be proud to know.